# Filtering on the date index in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I made `created_at` column as a date index to my `palma` data frame and I'm trying to filter on it but it's not working:

```
palma.Created_at = pd.to_datetime(palma.Created_at).dt.date
palma.set_index('Created_at')
palma = palma[palma.index != '2018-09-21'] #this is not affecting any row
palma = palma[palma.Created_at != '2018-09-21'] # not working also
```

`Created_at` looks like :

```
| Created_at| 
| ----------|
| 2019-10-20| 
| 2019-10-20| 
| 2019-10-20|
```

So how can I filter to exclude this day `2018-09-21`?

Comment: remove `.dt.date` from your first line code, then this will work `palma[palma.index != '2018-09-21']`

Comment: then the index will be `2019-10-20 10:08:4` how i can make it `2019-10-20`

Comment: try `palma.index.normalize() != '2018-09-21'`

Answer (score 1):

Pandas DataFrame `set_index` method require the `inplace` parameter to assign it inplace, hence:

```
palma.Created_at = pd.to_datetime(palma.Created_at).dt.date
palma.set_index('Created_at', inplace=True)
palma = palma[palma.index != '2018-09-21']
```

which redefines `palma` excluding every row with index `'2018-09-21'`

Answer (score 0):

Change the last two lines to

```
palma = palma.set_index('Created_at')
palma = palma[palma.index != '2018-09-21']
```

Comment: no it didn't work i added a photo to show you that no rows removed

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.to_datetime` on date.

```
palma = palma[palma.Created_at !=  pd.to_datetime('2018-09-21')]
```